# Querying and returning JSON data using a join table will transform the value of the value in the array into a string

Tags: php, yii2

What should I do? Please help, thank you！
There is plastic data in the array, but it's all string

```
$query = ProductInfo::find()
        ->select(ProductInfo::tableName() . '.*,' . ProductStock::tableName() . '.product_uid,total_stock,useful_stock,freeze_stock,warehouse_uid ,' . Category::tableName() . '.category_name,'.ProductBrand::tableName().'.name,'.Product::tableName().'.type')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', ProductStock::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.product_uid = ' . ProductStock::tableName() . '.product_uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN',Product::tableName(),ProductInfo::tableName().'.product_uid='.Product::tableName().'.uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', Category::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.category_uid =' . Category::tableName() . '.uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', ProductBrand::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.product_brand_uid =' . ProductBrand::tableName() . '.uid')
        ->Where([Product::tableName().'.type'=>0,ProductInfo::tableName().'.delete_flag' => 0])
        ->andFilterWhere(['or',
            ['like', 'product_name', $keyword],
            ['like', 'serial_number', $keyword],
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

There is nothing wrong, but my data has been transformed into a string, and I need it to be output according to the data type of the data

```
enter code here   {
"id": "2",
"uid": "1494645615632806007962",
"product_uid": "3213213213213213213211",
"product_name": "xxx2",
"product_brand_uid": "123456",
"brand_name": "wisss"………………},
```

Like id: "2", it should have been “id”:2
When I delete asArray (), the data type displayed is normal.
But there is only one table of data.

I've found that as long as a table queries and returns data in JSON format, this happens.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you think is the problem? Or the error that is showing or any other usefull information.

Comment: I've already shown it to you.When I'm not using asArray (), that's normal, but I don't have the query information for other tables

Comment: I've found that as long as a table queries and returns data in JSON format, this happens

Comment: this might help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the desired behavior.

**Retrieving Data in Arrays:**

> Note: While this method (asArray) saves memory and improves performance, it is
>   closer to the lower DB abstraction layer and you will lose most of the
>   Active Record features. A very important distinction lies in the data
>   type of the column values. When you return data in Active Record
>   instances, column values will be automatically typecast according to
>   the actual column types; on the other hand when you return data in
>   arrays, column values will be strings (since they are the result of
>   PDO without any processing), regardless their actual column types.

I think you can use something like:

```
$query = ProductInfo::find()
        ->select(ProductInfo::tableName() . '.*,' . ProductStock::tableName() . '.product_uid,total_stock,useful_stock,freeze_stock,warehouse_uid ,' . Category::tableName() . '.category_name,'.ProductBrand::tableName().'.name,'.Product::tableName().'.type')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', ProductStock::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.product_uid = ' . ProductStock::tableName() . '.product_uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN',Product::tableName(),ProductInfo::tableName().'.product_uid='.Product::tableName().'.uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', Category::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.category_uid =' . Category::tableName() . '.uid')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', ProductBrand::tableName(), ProductInfo::tableName() . '.product_brand_uid =' . ProductBrand::tableName() . '.uid')
        ->Where([Product::tableName().'.type'=>0,ProductInfo::tableName().'.delete_flag' => 0])
        ->andFilterWhere(['or',
            ['like', 'product_name', $keyword],
            ['like', 'serial_number', $keyword],
        ]);

$productsAsArray = ArrayHelper::toArray($query->all());
```

Let me know if it works.For more details, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9329) and this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#data-in-arrays).

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been solved in your own way

Comment: But my other list data doesn't show only info tables